# Why does Raspberry Pi 4 do not support USB boot?

Tags: usb, boot, pi-4, bootloader

I was searching for a way to boot from USB on RPi4. But I am always finding articles that is telling me that 3B+ has this boot feature but RPi4 doesn't.
After some more finding I found that this is because of the rpi-eeprom package does not have support for USB booting on RPi4. But there is a beta bootloader that can add this boot support.
My questions are:

1. When will Pi4 officially support this feature?
2. Is the beta bootloader safe to use?
3. How to use the beta bootloader?

Comment: USB boot is now in the stable eeprom (not the critical one) - so .. I guess the answers are 1 - now, 2 - it's not beta any more and 3 - don't use the beta, use stable - some links to read ... https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/booteeprom.md and https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711_bootloader_config.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. When will Pi4 officially support this feature?

[Since 2020-06-15](https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-eeprom/blob/master/firmware/release-notes.md#2020-06-17-promote-2020-06-15-to-stable)

> 2. Is the beta bootloader safe to use?

The beta bootloader is promoted to be stable (see link above). So it should be safe to use.

> 3. How to use the beta bootloader?

Have a look at [Pi 4 Bootloader Configuration](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711_bootloader_config.md)